# Python 2.7: Unable to read command output from terminal using StringIO() and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting the following error when trying to read the output from a command from terminal using `StringIO`, this script is working fine in `Python 3.x`, however due to requirements in our environment I need to run this script in `Python 2.7`, any help to resolve this is appreciated:

**Error**

```
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not _io.StringIO
```

**Script which is working fine in Python 3.x, but not working in 2.7**

```
interface_status = connect.send_command('show ip int brief',expect_string=r'#')
old_stdout = sys.stdout
interface_result = StringIO()
sys.stdout = interface_result
sys.stdout = old_stdout
data_xe = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(interface_result),  widths=[23, 16, 4, 7, 22, 8])

print(data_xe)
```

**I have tried adding unicode before the variable, but it gives me blank data:**

```
data_xe = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(unicode(interface_result)),  widths=[23, 16, 4, 7, 22, 8])
```

Comment: Add anaconda, you don't need to be root to install. Create an env with python3 and it will work.

Comment: I am running this in a Linux server, installed Python 3 inside the virtual environment, but still when I check the version, the virtual environment is running on 2.7

Comment: Have you try to use directly the python3 of your env in anaconda/envs/your env/bin?

Comment: No this is inside a corporate environment I dont have permissions to change anything

Comment: Ok, but how you send your think to the server ?

Comment: This script runs in a linux server with Python 2.7, it will connect to network devices and get some command output, but the stringIO is not reading this output in Python 2.7

Comment: Normally, when you send your script in python you write `python your_script.py`, instead of python use `~/anaconda3/envs/Myenv/bin/python3.7 your_script.py` with your directory.